# DF finite abelian groups and primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, prime-numbers

[image]

I follow this proof until the last 3 lines, I see why $\langle y^p\rangle \neq \langle y\rangle$ but how does this imply that $|y^p| < |y| ? $

I have been stuck on this for a long time, any help would be amazing.

thank you !

Comment: Isn’t this just the definition of order?

Comment: @Randall I am not seeing it, I think I am missing something but I dont think it follows straight from the definition of order right ?

Comment: Standard notation is $\langle y^p\rangle \neq \langle y\rangle,$ not $<y^p> \neq <y>.$ I edited this question accordingly. You can google "latex symbols" to see how to code things like this.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, I am sorry and thank you !

Comment: Note that $\langle y^p \rangle $ is a **subgroup** of $\langle y\rangle $ and $\langle y\rangle $  is of finite order.

Comment: @Koro GOT IT! thank you so much, also if you want to write that as an answer I will accept it !

Comment: Glad that you got it :). You can post your own answer to your question. :)

Comment: Please do not use images to convey information that is not elsewhere in your post. [See here to see why this is bad](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I am sorry I did not know about this. I will fix it as soon as I can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a finite cyclic group $C$ of order $n$ there is exactly one subgroup of each order $d\mid n$. So, in particular, if $a\in C$, and $\langle a\rangle \ne C$ then the order of $a$  $=$ $|\langle a\rangle|<n$.